# gradle-experimental:0.1.0 buildConfigField

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-experimental

Anyone know how to define `buildConfigField` in the experimental gradle plugin?

```
android.productFlavors {
    create("demo") {
        applicationId = 'com.anthonymandra.rawdroid'
        buildConfigField "String", FIELD_META, PROVIDER_META
    }
```

gives:

> Error:Attempt to read a write only view of model of type
>   'java.lang.Object' given to rule 'model.android.productFlavors'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `buildType` you can use a syntax like this:

```
android.buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigFields.with {
            create() {
                type = "String"
                name = "FIELD_META"
                value = "PROVIDER_META"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if you can use the same syntax with flavors.

Comment: This with another missing feature were holding me back from attempting simple ndk code again (*cough* two years after eclipse).  Since I have a possible answer on the other question after my next release I'll give the experimental plugin another shot, thanks.

Comment: @Anthony  Try also to update the plugin to the last `com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1`

Comment: No dice, I don't even get a proper error message now.  Just suggests I re-download dependencies .

Comment: Scratch that I archived my earlier attempt and it doesn't crash in the same manner, however you cannot define flavorized config fields currently.

Comment: Scratch that as well.  I am not crashing with buildConfigs in flavors now.  The Gradle sync is finicky with the new system.  Can't confirm it actually works yet, but this is definitely the way they intend us to implement it for the moment.