# gradle-experimental resValue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to set my appName per flavor in Android Studio. I use com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0 plugin so I can`t use standard gradle/groovy syntax.

I have found a solution here: [how to change android app name in the build gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607020/how-to-change-android-app-name-in-the-build-gradle-file)

However with all my experimentations I just can`t figure out the right syntax for resValue field.

I have tried something like this:

```
buildConfigFields.resValue = {
            create() {
                type = "String"
                name = "appName"
                value = "Game_Name"
            }
        }
```

But no luck.

Comment: You could use override the strings in the folder used by the flavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in your app/build.gradle

```
android {
 .....
 .....
 productFlavors {
  flavor1 {
   resValue "string", "app_name", "App-Name Flavor1"
  }
  flavor2 {
   resValue "string", "app_name", "App-Name Flavor2"
  }
 }
}
```

Note: Remove string **app_name** from **strings.xml**

### Edit :

This above approach **doesn't** work with given 0.4.0 plugin.

As suggested by @Gabriele Mariotti, you can try overriding the value of app_name string in that flavour.
Here's how you do it.

Add app_name string in respective strings.xml file

```
src
-- main/res/values/strings.xml (default value)
-- flavour1/res/values/strings.xml
-- flavour2/res/values/strings.xml
```

Comment: It doesn`t work with experimental 0.4.0 plugin. I have "Error:No signature of method: org.gradle.model.ModelMap.resValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [String, app_name, App-Name Flavor1]" error on gradle sync. I have tried String with capital S and small S as you wrote.

Comment: I have tried  resValue{
                create() {
                    type = "String"
                    name = "appName"
                    value = "Game_Name"
                }
            } And I have Error:Attempt to mutate closed view of model of type 'java.lang.Object' given to rule 'model.android.productFlavors' error

Comment: I understand now. I have already done this and it works. Since everything in the flavor folder takes precedence over the main folder. However I am looking for a way to set this String value from a txt file. So I am looking for a way in gradle to override this since I know how to parse a txt file and use the values of that.

Comment: I get an error: ` Could not find method resValue() for arguments [String, ENVIRONMENT, debug]`

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to override the string in the strings file in the flavor folder.

So create the following files:

```
src/flavor1/res/values/strings.xml
src/flavor2/res/values/strings.xml
```

Then add in these files the value of the app name

```
 <string name="app_name">XXXX</string>
```

Comment: I am familiar with this, but is there a way to set this value from gradle?

Comment: @AdrianIvasku See **xp-vit**'s answer below, as it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working with "gradle-experimental:0.8.0-rc2'"

```
model {
    android {
        defaultConfig {
        ...
            resValues.with {
                create() {
                    type = "string"
                    name = "myVar"
                    value = "myValue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that I was able to access this variable in my code using:

```
R.string.myVar
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works perfectly in gradle-experimental.  How did you figure this out?  Thanks.

Comment: I already had solution for "buildConfigFields.with" in my build.gradle found I believe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683438/gradle-experimental0-1-0-buildconfigfield . So I just tried to do similar and it worked.